# Taking a screenshot of a remote login

Tags: windows, screenshot

How do I take a screenshot of a remote login including the blue title bar that looks something like

```
_____________________________
\ -| .:|   ip address  -[] X/
```

I'm writing some documentation which needs a picture with 2-3 of these bars.  I tried taking a picture with a mobile phone but it seems to have blue lines all over.

**Edit**
I have tried Windows Snipping tool and all the combinations of PrtSc.  They only capture what is behind the blue bars.  They will not capture the blue bars.  The only way I've managed to capture them so far is to run a VM, remote in from the VM and use a snipping tool from the host but if I remote in from the host, I can't capture the bars.

Comment: Use a Windows screen capture tool  - there are numerous of these.  I use SnagIt and occasionally Windows Snipping tool.

Comment: Windows snipping tool and PrtSc do not capture the bars - they capture what is behind the bars.

Comment: Try a trial version of SnagIt.  If I can see it, I can capture it

Comment: Snagit works.  Just tried snipping tool again.  That worked too.  I think I know what my problem was - I launched the snipping tool from the remote rather than the host.

Comment: I posted an answer for you and hopefully you will follow up

Answer (score 0):

The best way for screen shots is SnagIt from Techsmith.

I have used SnagIt for years with Virtual machines and Remote sessions.

I use Snipping tool occasionally but SnagIt is best.

This is what I recommend.

Comment: Yes, I have followed it up - used the free version.  Had to go through signing up etc.  That works fine if you have an internet connection.  Problem is I can't do this at work because we are on a LAN that has no internet access.

Comment: The answer I gave you is what 99% of us do (one of the Apps ). No internet means you are totally hampered